# Import Excel / Array data to a database

Tags: excel, database, vb.net

I'm writing a code in VB to have a company site with updated employee information.
My goal was to:
 collect certain data from an Excel file
 Save the data into an 2D Array
 Update the array data into a database that is accessible by the website
 create the website and easly use the database data (so the site can easly be edited)

i have run into two problems :

1. i used a Try & Catch to resolve a Nullreference Exception on blank cells - the script is very slow when reading cols with alot off blank cells
2. I don't know how to correctly put the collected data  into a database (sql accces / not important)

Currently we use an Excel file with macro's & Excel VB to generate the site (having output directly written to an html file - so it's very static..)

Due to private employee information i cannot share the excel file, but i shared the code (i know, it's a bit sloppy since this is the first time i have worked with excel data, so i have done alot off 're-editing' my code)

(at the end i added a listbox1 update to verify the last record is correctly added )

If there are better solutions (direct import from excel to database) , please share :)

Thanks to you all in advance!

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class WieiswieForm
    Private Sub WieiswieForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Public Sub ChoseFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChoseFile.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel | *.xlsm"
        Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        FileTextBox.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        UpdateButton.Enabled = True

    End Sub


    Public Sub UpdateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpdateButton.Click

        UpdateButton.Enabled = False

        ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": starten...")

        Dim Filepath As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim Afdeling_cell As String = "C"
        Dim Functie_cell As String = "D"
        Dim Naam_cell As String = "E"
        Dim Organistaie_cell As String = "N"
        Dim Badgenummer_cell As String = "R"
        Dim Draagbaar_cell As String = "Y"
        Dim VastNummer_cell As String = "X"
        Dim GSM_cell As String = "AB"
        Dim Werkrooster_cell As String = "AE"
        Dim Normtijd_cell As String = "AF"
        Dim Afwezigheid_cell As String = "AG"
        Dim Vestiging_cell As String = "AI"

        Dim Cell_index(11) As String
        Cell_index(0) = Naam_cell
        Cell_index(1) = Afdeling_cell
        Cell_index(2) = Functie_cell
        Cell_index(3) = Organistaie_cell
        Cell_index(4) = Vestiging_cell
        Cell_index(5) = Werkrooster_cell
        Cell_index(6) = VastNummer_cell
        Cell_index(7) = Draagbaar_cell
        Cell_index(8) = GSM_cell
        Cell_index(9) = Afwezigheid_cell
        Cell_index(10) = Badgenummer_cell
        Cell_index(11) = Normtijd_cell


        If Filepath = "" Then
            MsgBox("Geen bestand geselecteerd..")

        Else
            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": Excel bestand openen...")
            Dim range As Excel.Range
            Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter


            ' Get the Excel application object.
            Dim excel_app As New Excel.ApplicationClass()

            ' Make Excel visible (optional).
            excel_app.Visible = False

            ' Open the workbook read-only.
            Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook =
        excel_app.Workbooks.Open(
        Filename:=Filepath, ReadOnly:=True)

            ' Get the first worksheet.
            Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet =
        DirectCast(workbook.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

            ' Get the number of rows (to avoid an index out-of-range)
            Dim LastRow As Integer
            LastRow = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

            '################## SUB START

            'Create the data array
            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": data verzamel object maken...")
            Dim DataArray(11, LastRow - 1) As String

            'Create the object to retrieve the data from the range 
            Dim saRet(,) As Object
            Dim iRows As Long
            Dim iCols As Long

            ' #########################################################################################

            ' Start the data colletion loop
            Dim arrayindex1 As Integer = 0
            Dim arrayindex2 As Integer = 0
            Dim c As Integer = 0

            ProgressBar1.Value = 10

            'Namen oplijsten :
            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": namen ophalen...")
            MaakArray(arrayindex1, arrayindex2, c, sheet, LastRow, range, saRet, iRows, iCols, Cell_index, DataArray)

            'Afdeling ophalen
            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": afdelingen ophalen...")
            ProgressBar1.Value = 20
            c = c + 1 '1
            arrayindex1 = arrayindex1 + 1
            arrayindex2 = 0
            MaakArray(arrayindex1, arrayindex2, c, sheet, LastRow, range, saRet, iRows, iCols, Cell_index, DataArray)

            'Functie binnen de afdeling : 
            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": functies ophalen...")
            ProgressBar1.Value = 30
            c = c + 1 '2
            arrayindex1 = arrayindex1 + 1
            arrayindex2 = 0
            MaakArray(arrayindex1, arrayindex2, c, sheet, LastRow, range, saRet, iRows, iCols, Cell_index, DataArray)

            'Organisatie ophalen

            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": organisaties ophalen...")
            ProgressBar1.Value = 40
            c = c + 1 '3
            arrayindex1 = arrayindex1 + 1
            arrayindex2 = 0
            MaakArray(arrayindex1, arrayindex2, c, sheet, LastRow, range, saRet, iRows, iCols, Cell_index, DataArray)

            'Vestiging ophalen

            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": vestigingen ophalen...")
            ProgressBar1.Value = 50
            c = c + 1 '4
            arrayindex1 = arrayindex1 + 1
            arrayindex2 = 0
            MaakArray(arrayindex1, arrayindex2, c, sheet, LastRow, range, saRet, iRows, iCols, Cell_index, DataArray)

            'werkrooster ophalen

            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": werkroosters ophalen...")
            ProgressBar1.Value = 60
            c = c + 1 '5
            arrayindex1 = arrayindex1 + 1
            arrayindex2 = 0
            MaakArray(arrayindex1, arrayindex2, c, sheet, LastRow, range, saRet, iRows, iCols, Cell_index, DataArray)

            'vastnummer ophalen

            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": vaste telefoonnummers ophalen...")
            ProgressBar1.Value = 70
            c = c + 1 '6
            arrayindex1 = arrayindex1 + 1
            arrayindex2 = 0
            MaakArray(arrayindex1, arrayindex2, c, sheet, LastRow, range, saRet, iRows, iCols, Cell_index, DataArray)

            'draagpaar ophalen

            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": draagbarenummers ophalen...")
            ProgressBar1.Value = 75
            c = c + 1 '7
            arrayindex1 = arrayindex1 + 1
            arrayindex2 = 0
            MaakArray(arrayindex1, arrayindex2, c, sheet, LastRow, range, saRet, iRows, iCols, Cell_index, DataArray)

            'GSM ophalen

            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": GSM nummers ophalen...")
            ProgressBar1.Value = 80
            c = c + 1 '8
            arrayindex1 = arrayindex1 + 1
            arrayindex2 = 0
            MaakArray(arrayindex1, arrayindex2, c, sheet, LastRow, range, saRet, iRows, iCols, Cell_index, DataArray)

            'Afwezigheden ophalen
            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": Afwezigheden nummer ophalen...")
            ProgressBar1.Value = 85
            c = c + 1 '9
            arrayindex1 = arrayindex1 + 1
            arrayindex2 = 0
            MaakArray(arrayindex1, arrayindex2, c, sheet, LastRow, range, saRet, iRows, iCols, Cell_index, DataArray)

            'Badgenummers ophalen
            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": badgenummers ophalen...")
            ProgressBar1.Value = 90
            c = c + 1 '10
            arrayindex1 = arrayindex1 + 1
            arrayindex2 = 0
            MaakArray(arrayindex1, arrayindex2, c, sheet, LastRow, range, saRet, iRows, iCols, Cell_index, DataArray)

            'Normtijd ophalen
            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": Normtijd ophalen...")
            ProgressBar1.Value = 95
            c = c + 1 '10
            arrayindex1 = arrayindex1 + 1
            arrayindex2 = 0
            MaakArray(arrayindex1, arrayindex2, c, sheet, LastRow, range, saRet, iRows, iCols, Cell_index, DataArray)



            ' Save the changes and close the workbook.
            workbook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)

            ' Close the Excel server.
            excel_app.Quit()

            ProgressBar1.Value = 100

            ListBox1.Items.Add(DateAndTime.Now.ToString & ": Bestand opgeladen!")
            ListBox1.Items.Add(DataArray(0, 501) & " " & DataArray(1, 501) & " " & DataArray(2, 501) & " " & DataArray(3, 501) & DataArray(4, 501) & DataArray(5, 501) & DataArray(6, 501) & DataArray(7, 501) & DataArray(8, 501))
            UpdateButton.Enabled = True
            MsgBox((DataArray(0, 501) & " " & DataArray(1, 501) & " " & DataArray(2, 501) & " " & DataArray(3, 501) & " " & DataArray(4, 501) & " " & DataArray(5, 501) & " " & DataArray(6, 501) & " " & DataArray(7, 501) & " " & DataArray(8, 501) & " " & DataArray(9, 501) & " " & DataArray(10, 501)))
        End If
    End Sub




Sub MaakArray(arrayindex1 As Integer, arrayindex2 As Integer, c As Integer, sheet As Excel.Worksheet, LastRow As Integer, range As Excel.Range, saret As Object, iRows As Long, iCols As Long, Cell_index() As String, ByRef DataArray(,) As String)


    Dim LoopTime As Integer = 0
    Do Until LoopTime = 11

        'Get a range of data.
        range = sheet.Range(Cell_index(c) & "2", Cell_index(c) & LastRow)

        'Retrieve the data from the range.
        saret = range.Value

        'Determine the dimensions of the array.
        iRows = saret.GetUpperBound(0)
        iCols = saret.GetUpperBound(1)

        'Build a string that contains the data of the array.
        Dim valueString As String
        'valueString = "" + vbCrLf



        Dim rowCounter As Long
        Dim colCounter As Long
        Dim i As Integer
        For rowCounter = 1 To iRows
            For colCounter = 1 To iCols


                'Write the next value into the string.

                Try
                    valueString = saret(rowCounter, colCounter).ToString()
                    'If String.IsNullOrEmpty(valueString) Then
                    'valueString = ""
                    ' End If
                Catch
                    valueString = ""

                End Try



                DataArray(arrayindex1, arrayindex2) = valueString


                If arrayindex2 = LastRow - 1 Then
                    arrayindex2 = arrayindex2
                Else
                    arrayindex2 = arrayindex2 + 1
                End If


                ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Value + 1 / 10

            Next colCounter

        Next rowCounter
        LoopTime = LoopTime + 1

    Loop


    '#########################################################################


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The database you are going to use does make a difference. There is an ADO.net provider for Excel. The speed isn't very important because you are only going to this once, right? Once the data is in the database these Excel sheets are history. Are the sheets that need to be imported consistent?

Comment: Is there any reason to import into any database?  Why not just have the website access the data directly out of the excel spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi,, thanks for the responses.

Mary : the sheets are updated every day (they create a new one every day based on personnel data)
So the database will have to be updated every day
There are some cells to determine if the person is avaible, and if they are sick / absent.

Hursey:
since they create a new excel file every day, the name of the file changes (based on an application managed by an external company)
Otherwise it could be an option

Comment: Mary & Hursey : you might have a good idea - Edit Update: the Excel file has a consistent name (year <space> month <space> day)
So if i could directly import the data into a database, or use as database for the website.. this would be great
i will do some extra research on this, thanks!

Comment: Once you have data in a database, it would make sense to have the updates made to the database not an Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Just for grins try the following and see what you get. You may have to adjust the HDR=YES to HDR=NO in the connection string. Add a DataGridView to your form so you can see the results. This at least will introduce you to the data provider for Excel. Once you have a DataTable you can update a database if you have a Primary Key.

Add to the top of the file

Imports System.Data.OleDb

The in the form code

```
Private Sub btnLoadGrid_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLoadGrid.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim strFileName As String = "Your file path"
    Dim strCon As String = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={strFileName};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
    Using cn = New OleDbConnection(strCon)
        Debug.Print(cboSheets.Text)
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand($"Select * From [Sheet1$];", cn)
            cn.Open()
            Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                dt.Load(dr)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```